# React Native - data is lost when switching between screens using react-navigation and react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am using react-redux and react-navigation with my react native app.

I have a component called `photolist` that gets all the photos from a database. There are two screens that call this component. The `userProfile` screen passes **true and userId** to `photolist` for the user's photos; the `feed` screen passes **false and null** to `photolist` for the all the photos.

In App.js, I put the Feed screen and User screen in the same stack so I can navigate easily.

With this approach, I am able to load the main page on App load, see all the photos, then go to a user's page and see the user's photos. **But from the user's page, when I click the back button to go back to the main page, no photos are loaded anymore.** Note that in this sequence of actions, the `photolist` component's `componentDidMount()` function is called exactly twice; when going back to the main feed from userProfile, it is not called again.

Any idea on why is this happening and how may I resolve this? Is there a way to keep the navigation structure where clicking the back button from `userProfile` will take you back to where you were in the main feed page without needing to reload the main feed again?

photolist.js:

```
class PhotoList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const { isUser, userId } = this.props;

        // load a single user's photos or all photos
        if (isUser) {
            this.props.loadFeed(userId);
        } else {    
            this.props.loadFeed();
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <FlatList
                    data = {(this.props.isUser) ? this.props.userFeed : this.props.mainFeed}
                    keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index.toString()}

                    ...
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        mainFeed: state.feed.mainFeed,
        userFeed: state.feed.userFeed
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loadFeed
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PhotoList);
```

feed.js:

```
<PhotoList isUser={false} navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

userProfile.js:

```
<PhotoList isUser={true} userId={this.state.userId} navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

App.js:

```
const FeedScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  FeedStack: { screen: feed },
  UserProfile: { screen: userProfile }
});
```

Comment: Can you share your API action loadFeed()? Can you show a log of the state on return? As for going back try using the shouldComponentUpdate() lifecycle method to prevent re-render.

Comment: @Javan_Poirier how would I even use `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method to check if `loadFeed()` should be called? I see how it would work if I am on the same screen, but I am navigating between screens here. I can't just check for something like `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, _) { if (nextProps.navigation.state.routeName === "UserProfile") { return false } return true }`

Comment: It sounds like your `this.props.loadFeed` method is overwriting the same data when you navigate from Feed -> User. Could you store the data in a different location? Then you wouldn't have to worry about it being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation doesn't mount and unmount components when navigating within a stack. Instead, the components stay mounted and have [custom react-navigation lifecycle events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html#react-navigation-lifecycle-events).

Adding a [`<NavigationEvents>` component](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) to your scene is one way to fix your use case:

```js
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

class PhotoList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadFeed();
  }

  loadFeed = () => {
    const { isUser, userId } = this.props;

    // load a single user's photos or all photos
    if (isUser) {
      this.props.loadFeed(userId);
    } else {    
      this.props.loadFeed();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return {
      <View>
        <NavigationEvents
          onDidFocus={this.loadFeed}
        />
      </View>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to recommend an approach without knowing how you are managing your data. Where does the data from `loadFeed` go? Does one call overwrite the other?

Comment: One note about this solution is it might make more sense to just call `onDidFocus={this.componentDidMount}` because the feed needs to load at least once on mount anyway, and not use `loadFeed ` here but just put the logic in `componentDidMount`

Comment: And the only problem with this solution is in `UserProfile`, the feed is loaded twice. Once in `componentDidMount ` and again in `onDidFocus={this.componentDidMount}`

Comment: I updated my code with a call from `componentDidMount` to `this.loadFeed`. I suggest not using `componentDidMount` as a callback; instead, move that logic to another function and call that function from `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Is there a reason why your function is called `loadFeed`, exact same as the prop's `loadFeed`? Asking because if I rename it to anything else, I will get a **Can't find variable** error